# Swift cocoa - How to color overlay full screen

Tags: swift, cocoa

How can I put color on the whole screen?

[image: How to make this effect]

Comment: is that like quicktime player screen selection before recording screen?

Comment: yes, like quictime

Comment: Did you try [The most elegant way of creating a fullscreen overlay on Mac OS X (Lion)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272664/the-most-elegant-way-of-creating-a-fullscreen-overlay-on-mac-os-x-lion) and [Passing Click Through Transparent Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950657/passing-click-through-transparent-window/18023371#18023371)?